# How to search for 500 terms in a Kibana query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm running a 7.2 ELK stack, and I'm trying to search for say 500 possible values in 1 search term, something like:

author: Bill OR author: Jim OR author: Tim OR author: Steve OR author: Sam ...

I've tried to cut and paste a list into the search bar but that seems to not work well. Does anybody have any recommendations on how to search with lists like this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give more details on the part "seems to not work well"?

Comment: post `mapping` and also a couple sample documents. If you also can, then a expected result document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If the values are terms (single word), you can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) otherwise you have to use [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) with [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)**

**[Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) :**

> Returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in a provided field.
>   The terms query is the same as the term query, except you can search for multiple values.

```
"query": {
  "terms": {
    "author": [
      "bill", "jim", "tim", "steve", "sam"
    ]
  }
}
```

*Note: when using terms query we have to lower case each author*

**[Match Phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) with [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) :**

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "match_phrase": {
          "author": "Bill"
        }
      },
      {
        "match_phrase": {
          "author": "Jim"
        }
      },
      {
        "match_phrase": {
          "author": "Tim"
        }
      },
      {
        "match_phrase": {
          "author": "Steve"
        }
      },
      {
        "match_phrase": {
          "author": "Sam"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well. What would be great would be an interface in kibana for someone to just upload a text file, say a simple list (for users) and that be formatted into this KQL.